# I can not access dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, assign

With the following code, I am reading multiple csv files into dataframes.

```
setwd("/path/to/files")

filenames <- gsub("\\.csv$","", list.files(pattern="\\.csv$"))

for(i in filenames){
  assign(i, read.csv(paste(i, ".csv", sep="")))
}
```

When I try to access them in the following code

```
for (i in filenames) {
    imanDavenportTest(i)
}
```

I get the following error

```r
Error in apply(data, MARGIN = 1, FUN = f) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

can someone help me?

Comment: I guess you need to `get(i)`.

Comment: Using `assign()` is [almost always] bad. Make [a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/4497050) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edward's answer is correct. But I wanted to add a note as you are going about this in a quite complicated way and not taking full advantage of R.

There's no reason to use `assign` here. You can read in all your data in one go and have the results stored as a single object (a list) rather than having `N` objects polluting your workspace. For example:

```
# read files in your directory
file_ls <- list.files('.', pattern=".csv$")

# use lapply to read each file and create a list of data frames
data_ls <- lapply(file_ls, read.csv)

# perform the test on each element of the list
lapply(data_ls, imanDavenportTest)
```

`assign` is often adopted by people that are coming from languages that have global variables but it doesn't take advantage of R's object-orientated functional programming. IMHO, using `assign` in this manner creates code that is hard to read and fragile to maintain.

Comment: Might as well use `lapply` instead of `for` the second time, too.

Answer (score 2):

Your "filenames" are simply character strings representing the names of the data imported from `read.csv`. You need to `get` the *data* from these named objects.

So try:

```
for(i in filenames){
  imanDavenportTest(get(i))
}
```